# heroku discord bot stopped working after working fine for some time?

Tags: heroku, discord, discord.js, bots

I Programmed two discord bots for personal usage in js and hosted them on heroku.
they worked but a few days ago (two or three) they stopped working but I didn't change anything.
is there anything I need to change to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably that your bot has crashed too many time or that you have run out of Heroku hours

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours